Find minimum clock period for digital circuit
I have been given the following circuit:

I am given the respective propagation delays and asked to find the minimum clock period for proper functioning of the circuit without any glitches:

I calculated the delays and noted them down (my solution):

Based on this I entered 17 as Flip Flop A seemed to have the largest delay. However this is the incorrect answer.
I have ignored the NOT gate output delay as it is guaranteed to be ready by the time Tcq is ready (Tcq > Tnot). I have also assumed that the input x may be changed only at the same time as positive clock edge is triggered.
Where am I incorrect? How to approach it correctly?

Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to add an actual question. Currently I see just statements.

my question is where i went incorrect. I edited it.

What is the function of the x input?

@devnull Since this task is about calculation of clock periods, the circuit does not need to have a real use or to work at all. However, a quick simulation suggests that it lets the FSM advance at every second clock.

@thebusybee. Ok. Thanks. You meant advance by two each clock, right? X=0 blocks Qc and forces the flip of Qb each clock.

Please clarify, as asked by @devnull. It is important to know how exactly x changes in relation to the clock. This is probably relevant. -- Otherwise, at a first glance your calculations looks correct, if I assume that x receives a signal constantly over multiple clock periods.

@devnull Yes. Sorry for the wording, English is not my native language.

hi, i had the same confusion, but to keep things simple x changes exactly on positive clock edge.

Perhaps this is the source of the difference. You might need to ask the authors of the task.

Flip flip A (QA) doesn't go anyplace in this circuit.  So its delay is irrelevant to the toggle rate (clock rate) of this circuit.


but to keep things simple x changes exactly on positive clock edge

The question does seem to be missing relevant information. Input x should not be asynchronous, otherwise it would not be possible to guarantee correct timing (setup and hold). Since it needs to be synchronized, it is the output of another flip-flop, not simultaneous with the clock itself. If that is the case and this other flip-flop has the same propagation delay, 18 is indeed the critical path. The 6 would come from the other flip-flop, not the one in the diagram. The loop-back path with 17 ns delay would not be the critical one, if this synchronization is to be assumed.
I agree with the comment that recommends further clarification from the authors.

thank you very much. does this mean that if 1) x is a constant which never changes, Or 2) if it is strictly not coming from another flipflop, and it changes exactly at the same time as positive edge of clock, then the minimum period will be 17?

@mayabed Probably x is the output of another flip-flop clocked by the same clock, as described. It says something that the expected answer is "18" and not "17, but 18 if ..." However, only you can verify this by asking your teachers. That's why we asked for clarification.

thank you. i will ask them and get back... However, can you tell me if i was correct on the above scenarios in my previous comment?
